# When should I use property in C# Interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm new to C# interfaces, I know that inside Interfaces we can put some property like

```
int speed{ get; set; }
```

but things is that, the reason property exists is to achieve encapsulation, which provides access to private members, however in interfaces everything is public. Then does it make sense to use property in Interfaces? Or it's just because interfaces are "contracts" so this is sort of normal?

Comment: You got few things wrong. Properties do not exist for Encapsulation. Properties are short cuts to writing Getter/Setters for your Fields. You can apply modifiers to get or set individually too. Yes Interfaces are Contracts and so if you want an Info to be available to all implementers you can put it as Getter property or a Get method/function.

Comment: Say for Example - you define a contract IPerson representing Person in you School. Each person will have a Name, Age, ContactNumber, Id.
Some Person would be Students while some would be Teachers etc. So you think of Object/Data design Hierarchy and design your contracts to target that.

Comment: Read this as it might help you understand the interfaces better. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/#:~:text=An%20interface%20may%20not%20declare,support%20multiple%20inheritance%20of%20classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use properties in interfaces as public members that are part of your “contract”

> A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field [c# programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

So the backing field is private but the property is public. Therefore it can form part of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use properties. You can use methods too, like this:

```
public int GetSpeed();

public void SetSpeed(int n);
```

However, people seem to prefer using a property, and its `get` and `set` methods, because it is easier to read and use, and it encapsulates the getter and setter in one place.